# Excel Sumproduct equivalent in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sumproduct

I have a simple exercise, but cannot find a simple solution to it in Pandas. My dataframe has the following form:

```
         A      B      C      D              A1          B1          C1            D1
0       0.0    0.0    0.0  0.090909       0.247747    0.162398    0.381459       0.208396
1       0.0    0.0    0.0  0.090909       0.250811    0.168629    0.374599       0.205961
2       0.0    0.0    0.0  0.090909       0.252173    0.168521    0.374551       0.204755
```

I want to calculate the sum product of the columns using always A*A1 + B*B1 .. .D*D1

I found a solution, but it is a bit messy and not suitable as soon as the number of columns will increase. Any pythonic way to solve this? Using Excel I would you the `sumproduct` function.

Current solution:

```
df['SP'] = df[["A", 'A1']].prod(axis=1) + df[["B", 'B1']].prod(axis=1) + df[["C", 'C1']].prod(axis=1) + df[["D", 'D1']].prod(axis=1)
```

Should lead to:

```
 df[SP]
0.018945
0.018724
0.018614
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).prod().sum(1)`

Comment: That looks great, but would it be possible to be more dynamic with the column names and assign ranges or lists instead? In reality the columns names are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Chris' comment, but you can ignore the column names and pass the range instead:

```
num_base_cols=4
num_repeat = 2

col_groups = np.tile(np.arange(num_base_cols), num_repeat)

df.groupby(col_groups, axis=1).prod().sum(1)
```

Output:

```
0    0.018945
1    0.018724
2    0.018614
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the columns on the 'left' and 'right' and then multiply and `sum(axis=1)`.

Note that I'm assuming all of your columns follow the `col_name`/`col_name<number>` convention (if this is not the case, you will have to manually identify the column names in the lists `cols_left` and `cols_right`).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'A': [0,0,0],
    'B': [0,0,0],
    'C': [0,0,0],
    'D': [0.090909, 0.090909, 0.090909],
    'A1': [0.247747,0.250811, 0.252173],
    'B1': [0.162398, 0.168629, 0.168521],
    'C1': [0.381459, 0.374599, 0.374551],
    'D1': [0.208396, 0.205961, 0.204755]
})

cols_left = [c for c in df.columns if '1' not in c]
cols_right = [c for c in df.columns if '1' in c]

out = (df[cols_left] * df[cols_right].values).sum(axis=1)

out:

0    0.018945
1    0.018724
2    0.018614
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `(df[cols_left] * df[cols_right].values)` does? When trying out, I noticed that without `.values` it doesn't work. Why is `.values` needed?