# Equivalent of SUMPRODUCT in dataframe with strings

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the equivalent in Pandas of the PRODUCTSUM in Excel? I have this formula in Excel with PRODUCTSUM inside a conditional IF.

```
IF(PRODUCTSUM((A$2:A2=A2)*(C$2:C2=C2)*(B$2:B2=B2))>1;0;1)
```

I have found some examples in other posts like these:

[Excel Sumproduct equivalent in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435560/excel-sumproduct-equivalent-in-pandas)

but these refer to columns with integers and since my columns are composed of strings I do not know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Let's pretend my df is like:

```
A        B             C             Output          
'John'   'Sanchez'  'Active'         1
'Mike'   'Isner'    'Inactive'       1
'Mike'   'Isner'    'Inactive'       0
```

Comment: Will you please share a dataframe that you want to get? That makes it easier to visual the conditions.

Comment: What's the product of two strings?

Comment: See my edit with the desired output

Comment: can you give desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to find duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupy`

```
df['Output']=df.groupby(['A','B','C']).cumcount()
df.Output = df.Output + 1
df.loc[(df.Output > 1),"Output"] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks mate it solved the issue